# Pi Model tag naming is not consistent

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retagging

We have multiple tags for the various models of the Raspberry Pi: [model-a](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/model-a), [pi1](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi1), [pib+](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pib%2b), [pi2](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi2), and [pi-zero](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-zero)

And two related tags: [models](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/models) and [raspberry-pi-foundation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raspberry-pi-foundation)

As you can see, there are differences in hyphens, whether it says model or pi, etc. To make them consistent, I recommend these renames/retags:

[model-a](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/model-a) > [pi-a](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-a)

[pib+](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pib%2b) > [pi-b+](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-b%2b)

[pi2](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi2) > [pi-2](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-2)

[pi-zero](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-zero) > [pi-zero](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-zero) (to stick with official naming and keep it the same)

[pi1](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi1) (only has 11 questions, so should retag to specific models)

> [pi-b](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-b)

> [pi-a+](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-a%2b)\

[models](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/models) > [pi-models](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-models)

[raspberry-pi-foundation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raspberry-pi-foundation) > [pi-foundation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-foundation) (I created this tag for two specific questions; however it has been frequently misused (presumably) because  it is the only tag with the full word 'raspberry' in it. By renaming it, it will be pushed below the model tags in search and hopefully not abused)

---

This means we will end up with:

[pi-a](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-a), [pi-b](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-b), [pi-a+](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-a%2b), [pi-b+](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-b%2b), [pi-zero](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-zero), [pi-2](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-2)

And: [pi-models](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-models), [pi-foundation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-foundation)

Optionally we can add `raspberry-` to the start of every tag for better searchablility.

Comment: Hi, thank you for this good and useful suggestion. I'd consider the main part if it really helpful, but lets have some public discussion first before changing all of them.

Comment: ... and btw thanks for cleaning up the foundation tag right now.

Comment: Ok, we got it started. Things are changed they way you proposed it (w/o the foundation tag). Time to check the tag wiki entries ;)

Comment: Don't forget the [tag:compute-module]!

Comment: @Ghanima Could we please have compute module renamed too as per SlySeven's request?

Comment: @SlySven, actually there is no *request*, the tag's there. What do you want to have changed?

Comment: I didn't explicitly say I wanted anything changed - just that the compute model was not included in the above listing and we should not forget about it...! 8-) {Perhaps [tag:compute-module] might be revised to [tag:pi-compute-module] to fit in the scheme of things?}

Comment: Oh, and we do now have [tag:pi-1] for everything that isn't a multi-cored Pi 2...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**YES**, that would make the use of the tags more helpful for the whole site.

I like the consistent scheme of the model tags: [pi-a](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-a), [pi-b](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-b), [pi-a+](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-a%2b), [pi-b+](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-b%2b), [pi-zero](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-zero), [pi-2](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-2) as well as the clarification of [pi-models](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-models).

Personally I'd skip the additional prefix `raspberry-` for these tags as it is more or less redundant - we're talking about the Pi here.

However, I am reluctant with [pi-foundation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-foundation) and would keep that the old way [raspberry-pi-foundation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raspberry-pi-foundation). I think that shortening it will not prevent the frequent misuse. New users simply rely on it as a fall-back tag if nothing else fits.

Comment: The reason why I wanted to rename the foundation tag is because each time I look at it, it has 10 or more mistagged questions where we already had appropriate tags. Out of 50+ edits, I only had to create a new tag for 2 of them.

Comment: Yes, I am well aware that the tag is heavily misused, but I am not sure that this renaming will prevent this. On the other hand it has a well defined area of application (according to the tag description, which unfortunately most people do not seem to care about). And somehow it explicitely carries the *Raspberry Pi Foundation*'s real name. So as a proper noun I have strong feelings to keep it. Which brings us to the point preventing the misuse somehow else.

Comment: Prefixing the rest of the tags with `raspberry-` or maybe setting up synonyms to redirect to the model tags might help.. but that invalidates your other point